# If condition is true but react component is not render correctly inside the if statement

Tags: reactjs

```
// mainNavigation function

mainNavigation() {
 const {loggedIn} = this.props;

 if (loggedIn) {
  return (
    <button className="item blue-text blue-text-btn link-effect-1"
      onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>
  );
 } else {
  return (
    <a className="item blue-text link-effect-1" href="/signin">
      Sign In / Sign Up
    </a>
  );
 }
}

// render function 

render() {

return (
  <div className="menu" id="main-nav-desktop">
    <a className="active item home-link link-effect-1">
      Home
    </a>
    <a className="item link-effect-1">
      About Us
    </a>
    <a className="item link-effect-1">
      FAQ
    </a>
    <a className="item link-effect-1">
      Contact Us
    </a>
    <a className="item link-effect-1">
      Blog
    </a>
    {this.mainNavigation()}
  </div>
);
}
```

i'm trying to hide the **sign in/ sign up** link when the user logged in to the system 
first time when i logged into the system this work fine 
but when i try to log out and then logged in to the system again 
there is a **sign in / sign up** link instead of **log out** link

when i refresh again it work fine

how can i solve this ??

Comment: Probably the application state is not updated correctly. Please provide more complete code so we can find it out.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6e01d5bae5b3192a96b4d4527c1c8fa8

Comment: Pass the props to mainNavigation as parameter.

Comment: i already passed all the props to the component

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6e01d5bae5b3192a96b4d4527c1c8fa8
@Vijay

Comment: I was suggesting to pass to the function.  {this.mainNavigation(this.props.loggedIn)}

Comment: @Vijay mate that's not working :(

Comment: worth a try! is the flux plumbing working? when logging out, the store / context should be updated.